# error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type

Tags: c++, structure

As much as I want to create an MVCE of this problem...I really can't. I am using an open source fluid flow solver called Palabos with its dev guide also available . It is based on generic structures and mpi. Probably the best available open source solver of its kind

The developers there use Box Processors for cycling through arrays(generally speaking..it can be tensors, lattice are other objects). Here is a way they use processors for a single lattice case

```
struct IniTemperatureRayleighBenardProcessor2D :
    public BoxProcessingFunctional2D_L<T,adDescriptor>
{
    IniTemperatureRayleighBenardProcessor2D(RayleighBenardFlowParam<T,nsDescriptor,adDescriptor> parameters_)
        : parameters(parameters_)
    { }
    virtual void process(Box2D domain, BlockLattice2D<T,adDescriptor>& adLattice)
    {
        Dot2D absoluteOffset = adLattice.getLocation();
        Array<T,adDescriptor<T>::d> jEq(0.0, 0.0);

    for (plint iX=domain.x0; iX<=domain.x1; ++iX) {
        for (plint iY=domain.y0; iY<=domain.y1; ++iY) {
//some operations...............
        }
    }
    }
    virtual IniTemperatureRayleighBenardProcessor2D<T,nsDescriptor,adDescriptor>* clone() const
    {
        return new IniTemperatureRayleighBenardProcessor2D<T,nsDescriptor,adDescriptor>(*this);
}

virtual void getTypeOfModification(std::vector<modif::ModifT>& modified) const {
    modified[0] = modif::staticVariables;
}

virtual BlockDomain::DomainT appliesTo() const {
    return BlockDomain::bulkAndEnvelope;
}

private :
    RayleighBenardFlowParam<T,nsDescriptor,adDescriptor> parameters;
};
```

Here how they call it

```
   applyProcessingFunctional (
            new IniTemperatureRayleighBenardProcessor2D<T,NSDESCRIPTOR,ADESCRIPTOR>(parameters), adLattice.getBoundingBox(),
            adLattice );
```

Details of the whole procedure are at (http://www.palabos.org/documentation/userguide/data-processors.html)

with related source code at (http://www.palabos.org/documentation/develguide/dataProcessingFunctional2D_8h_source.html)

Now, here is my problem.
I am using a similar data processor to perform operation on two scalar arrays. Tried to understand as much as of the source code as possible

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
//template<typename T, template<typename NSU> class nsDescriptor,
//                     template<typename ADU> class adDescriptor, typename T1, typename T2>
struct IniFluxMultiplier2D :
    public BoxProcessingFunctional2D_SS<T,T>
{
    IniFluxMultiplier2D(RayleighBenardFlowParam<T,NSDESCRIPTOR,ADESCRIPTOR> parameters_)
        : parameters(parameters_)
    { }
    virtual void process(Box2D domain,
                         MultiScalarField2D<bool>& boolMask,
                         MultiScalarField2D<T> &FluxMultiplier)
        {
        //Dot2D absoluteOffset = adLattice.getLocation();
        //Array<T,adDescriptor<T>::d> jEq(0.0, 0.0);

        for (plint iX=domain.x0; iX<=domain.x1; ++iX) {
            for (plint iY=domain.y0; iY<=domain.y1; ++iY) {
                //plint absoluteX = absoluteOffset.x + iX;
                //plint absoluteY = absoluteOffset.y + iY;
                bool  solidblock = boolMask.get(iX,iY);

                if(solidblock== true){
                FluxMultiplier.get(iX,iY)=(parameters.getTemperatureTau()-(T)0.5)/parameters.getTemperatureTau();}
                else{
                FluxMultiplier.get(iX,iY)=(parameters.getSolventTau()-(T)0.5)/parameters.getSolventTau();}

        }
    }
    }
   virtual IniFluxMultiplier2D<T1,T2>* clone() const
    {
        return new IniFluxMultiplier2D<T1,T2>(*this);
    }

   virtual void getTypeOfModification(std::vector<modif::ModifT>& modified) const {
        modified[0] = modif::staticVariables;
    }

    virtual BlockDomain::DomainT appliesTo() const {
        return BlockDomain::bulkAndEnvelope;
    }

private :
    RayleighBenardFlowParam<T,NSDESCRIPTOR,ADESCRIPTOR> parameters;
};
```

and here is how I call it

```
applyProcessingFunctional (
        new IniFluxMultiplier2D<T,T>(parameters), boolMask.getBoundingBox(), boolMask,FluxMultiplier);
```

I am getting the error

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘IniFluxMultiplier2D<double, double>’|
```

Tried debugging it but I am stuck and really can't figure a way out. I don't really expect anyone to run this, but I know I am making a conceptual mistake at the starting of the structure which I can't really figure out.

T is decalared as

```
typedef double T;
```

globally

Comment: Is that the whole error message? (C++ errors can sometimes be very verbose; copy/paste the whole thing anyway)

Comment: Do you know what the error means?  It seems clear to me.  You derived from an abstract class (a class with one or more virtual functions that have the `= 0;` qualifier), and didn't implement all of those `= 0;` virtual functions in your derived class.

Comment: Presumably, you haven't overridden all the pure virtual functions of `BoxProcessingFunctional2D_SS`. Read the full error message to find out which. Check that all the functions are there, and all the parameter types and qualifiers match. If your compiler supports it, put `override` after each override to get better error messages.

Comment: In particular, check `process`, which is different in the two classes you've posted. If you want more than guesswork from us, post the definition of `BoxProcessingFunctional2D_SS` (and remove the irrelevant `IniTemperatureRayleighBenardProcessor2D ` class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `process()` is

```
virtual void process (Box2D domain, ScalarField2D< T1 > &field1, ScalarField2D< T2 > &field2)=0
```

But you are passing `MultiScalarField2D<T>&` and there does not seem to be an available conversion to `ScalareField2d<T>&`. So you have defined a new virtual function and not overridden the function in the base. Use of the `override` keyword helps in these situations.